# How do I compute distinct count on a column based on a user selection?

Tags: powerbi, aggregate-functions, dax

I have table with millions of rows, and I need to count distinct a column, after eliminating records using a user selection , say a table or slicer..

I tried the function , values  , distinct count .. none of them are working as expected .

```
unique opners = DISTINCTCOUNT( 'dw useraction_fact'[user_id])
```

I expect to get a distinct count of users acting to a project that I can select, but the distinct count is calculated for each project and it's summed up.

Comment: Is "unique openers" a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: it is a measure

Comment: The behavior you're talking about is very odd.  DISTINCTCOUNT should always be calculated in its current filter context, and never be the sum of some level of its component slices.  However, if you had put this formula into a calculated column, then you would see something that looked like an aggregate number calculated on each row, and ultimately summed up.